# Packaging up and sending a bike from UK to Europe

Tags: parts, gravel, travelling

I need to send my gravel bike (~11 kg) one way from the UK to Switzerland in a few weeks. As I am going by Eurostar part of the way, I was intending on using their Eurodespatch service, but this has been suspended indefinitely due to Covid-19.

**Does anyone know of a cheap and reliable service for posting a bike from the UK to Switzerland?**

Some couriers claim to post bikes but, when it comes to requesting a *quick quote*, they often just say that the parcel is too big or too heavy.

Also, any advice on how to dismantle and pack the bike up safely whilst saving space (will need to find a suitably small cardboard box) will be much appreciated.

Comment: Your LBS should have cardboard boxes for bikes. Many of those are going into recycling.anyway.

Comment: Many bike shops will pack and ship for you, often because of the savings on shipping the have, at very reasonable prices.

Comment: It might be easier to ship it bike shop to bike shop just because bike shops deal with that all the time and so do the couriers who deliver/pick up from bike shops. The alternative can be nasty... I currently have a bike frame lost by a courier company and I am certain with zero evidence that the van driver who was supposed to deliver it just looked at the enormous box and said "oops I lost it"

Comment: I can recommend the boxes from Canyon, they pack their bikes in these boxes for delivery and you can pick one from eBay for about 15€